# When do new gratitude crystal quests appear?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm tired of running around Skyloft every time I return from the surface or accomplish something elsewhere to look for new quests to earn gratitude crystals. At which points in the game do each of the side quests unlock?  I don't want to know what the quests are, just when I should go looking.

Comment: That's a hard one to determine without checking Skyloft after every major event.  I'd just go by when you complete a dungeon (and not the sub-quest of being able to enter it) as that always seemed when new stuff came up.

Comment: Since you seem to be okay with spoiling everything upcoming in the game... you do know what the rewards for gratitude crystals are, right? And that you'll be perfectly all right if you don't get them all immediately? So you could just go along with the main quest for a while, then check back when several side quests have probably opened up.

Comment: @Jefromi Ouch! Sorry. I like to complete everything as I work through a game, finishing at or near 100% when I finish the main story.

Comment: @splatteredbits: Sure. But still, the worst case is, you do a lot of side quests at the end of the main story, and if you only look around once every couple temples, you'll be plenty faster than that. (And you'll probably be fine in the main quest without having the rewards at the earliest possible time.)

Comment: @Jefromi  You play your way, I'll play mine.  If you don't like the question, down vote it or don't read it or both.

Comment: @splatteredbits: Sure. I was just trying to suggest that you might be able to be less frustrated by doing a few at once (and have less travel time to boot), since doing them at the first opportunity means that there's only ever one available, so the searching is more painful (since you said you don't want to know the quests, so you don't know who to find for them). All I knew of your way of play was that you wanted to 100% it, which was compatible with what I was saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ZeldaDungeon.net](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14-skyward-sword-gratitude-crystals.php) (don't click the link if you don't want to know the quests), the requirements are (in no particular order):

> - Requirements: Complete Skyview Temple
> - Requirements: Meet Batreaux, and learn about Gratitude Crystals (this is the only sidequest that rewards 10 gratitude crystals, make sure you get both bunches!)
> - Requirements: Complete Lanayru Mining Facility
> - Requirements: Complete Lanayru Mining Facility (there are two)
> - Requirements: Acquire Scrapper
> - Requirements: Defeat The Imprisoned.
> - Requirements: Obtain the Clawshots
> - Requirements: Use the item check frequently
> - Requirements: Defeat The Imprisoned a second time.
> - Requirements: Defeat Levias, Speak with Strich on Bug Rock
> - Requirements: Complete Faron's portion of the Song of the Hero
> - Requirements: Complete Din's portion of the Song of the Hero

And for the individiual, non-quest Gratitude Crystals, just note that some of them require the Clawshots (or, alternatively, the Beetle speed/distance upgrades).

Answer (score 4):

- Sidequest 1: After puttting the Ruby Tablet in the Statue of the Goddess
- Sidequest 2: After Completing Sidequest 1
- Sidequest 3: After you talk to the old lady after obtaining the harp.
- Sidequest 4: After the third temple, when a certain potion has become available
- Sidequest 5: After getting the Clawshots
- Sidequest 6: Complete of the Fire Sanctuary, and the Pumpkin jobs.
- Sidequest 7: After you reseal the seal for the second time.
- Sidequest 8: Learn about a new island in the Thunderhead from the man standing besides the lighthouse after freeing Levias in the Thunderhead.
- Sidequest 9: After flirting with the item check girl.
- Sidequest 10: After getting the Gust Bellows
- Sidequest 11: After unlocking Thunderhead
- Sidequest 12: After ridding Levias of Bilocyte

([Source](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/Gratitude_Crystals) **FULL SPOILERS**)